# Compile class while running and use it

Tags: java, classloader

I want to make an interactive program which allows the users to change the behaviour of one method while the program is running. The user should be able to change everything between

```
public int result(){
```

and `}`.

Then, the program should be able to access this method and do what it needs to do.

Is this possible in java? I heard something about the ClassLoader, but was unable to find good tips how to use it.

Comment: There be dragons.  You can do it, but doing it repeatedly (with the same class) is difficult to impossible.  In addition to figuring out how to do the compile itself, you have to figure out some ugly details about class loading.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Java Runtime Compiler](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler) which takes code in a String, compiles it from memory and loads it into the current ClassLoader or one of your choice.

Here is a Hello World program

```
 String className = "mypackage.MyClass";
 String javaCode = "package mypackage;\n" +
                  "public class MyClass implements Runnable {\n" +
                  "    public void run() {\n" +
                  "        System.out.println("\"Hello World\");\n" +
                  "    }\n" +
                  "}\n";
 Class aClass = CompilerUtils.CACHED_COMPILER.loadFromJava(className, javaCode);
 Runnable runner = (Runnable) aClass.newInstance();
 runner.run();
```

In your case the String needs to look like

```
 String codeInMethod = ....
 String javaCode = "package mypackage;\n" +
                   "public class MyClass implements ReturnsInt {\n" +
                   "    public int result() {\n" +
                   codeInMethod +
                   "    }\n" +
                   "}\n";
```

You need to create the interface for it to implement as this is your way of calling the instance of the class once it is created. (Or you could use reflection which would be a shame)

Note: you should only do this for code you trust otherwise as the code can do anything to your machine.

Comment: Thanks, this looks nice. I´m getting 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory' for now, do i need this package? I don´t see any dependencies on the github page.

Comment: I´m trying to use Maven now, I hope this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Byte Buddy](http://bytebuddy.net) is your friend here.

It's a code generation library for creating Java classes during the runtime of a Java application and without the help of a compiler.

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible using a Class Loader. Java is a compiled language in which all instructions carried out by the computer are encoded or *compiled* from the code you write to a special *class* files. In order to have an interactive method be implemented for users, you would have to create your own Java interpreter. For more information, see here

> http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/82compiler/

Comment: And i´m not able to compile the code inside a java programm? At least it should be possible by using "javac" or not?

Comment: @Jakob I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that. Could you clarify?